# Datepicker in a while loop

Tags: php, html, datepicker

i have this issue.  I am trying to create a form page where it will show a list of data using a while loop and each of them have the input field option to choose a date which will all be submitted over. So far i have about 4 fields displayed but the datepicker only works for the first one. The rest are just empty text box.

**This my code :**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE Shortlist_status = 1 ORDER BY Candidate_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

<html>
<head>

    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">


     <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>   


</head>
    <title>
        Arrange interview
    </title>

<body>

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

(Some other input data)

<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/>

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class `datepicker` instead of unique id:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM application WHERE Shortlist_status = 1 ORDER BY Candidate_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

<html>
<head>

    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">


     <script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); // Change this line
});
</script>   


</head>
    <title>
        Arrange interview
    </title>

<body>

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

(Some other input data)

<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date"/> // Change this line

}
```

**Explanation:**

An attribute `id` should have a unique value. You cannot define 4 datepicker with the same id `datepicker`. Instead, you should use the attribute `class`. Your JQuery's selector becomes then `$('.datepicker')`.